# run docker on overlay network failed

Tags: docker, overlay

I create an overlay network successfully, but when I create a docker container using this network it fails:

```
docker  run --net my_overlay --name test -it centos6 bash
```

> docker: Error response from daemon: could not add veth pair inside the network sandbox: could not find an appropriate master "ov-000100-00d00" for "vethdee0c9b".

The node's ip address is 10.16.26.118 and the original start daemon command is:

```
/usr/bin/docker daemon \
--insecure-registry dockerhub.xxx.com \
--cluster-store=etcd://10.16.24.153:2379,10.16.24.152:2379,10.16.25.54:2379 \
--cluster-advertise=10.16.26.118:2379
```

The output from `docker network ls` is:

```
[root@sa-docker-test1.db01:~]# docker network ls 
NETWORK ID NAME DRIVER SCOPE 
30244c91aa3a bridge bridge local 
1bbaecaa70af host host local 
00d00c478d12 my_overlay overlay global 
a112d2eb8504 net1 calico global 
32a81070bb49 none null local
```

Comment: I did not use docker machine since I run docker on vm which driver is kvm.Did I need to configure the vm's network to fit docker's multihost network?Or I should run some software to support vxlan or something else

Comment: show `docker network ls` output

Comment: @NguyenSyThanhSon `[root@sa-docker-test1.db01:~]# docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
30244c91aa3a        bridge              bridge              local               
1bbaecaa70af        host                host                local               
00d00c478d12        my_overlay          overlay             global        
a112d2eb8504        net1                calico              global              
32a81070bb49        none                null                local  `

Comment: Is it possible that your docker daemon is failing to communicate with the etcd service? It's worth checking that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without use docker machine,I can't use the overlay network.
So,I turn to use calico network,this is easy to configure and easy to understand.